# Android Studio and SMBJ

Tags: android, smb, smbj

I am trying to make a File List from my SMB Shared Folder with Android Studio.

I want to press a Button in my Android App and then get the List stored as `*.txt` in my root or SD Card Root.

I am using Android Studio API Version Level 30 and SMBJ Library.

But I'm failing in connection for my SMB Share.

When I press the button with the code its crashing without giving a Message on my Samsung Galaxy S20.

I found that the crash happens on following 2 lines:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("admin", "password123".toCharArray(),null);
Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);
```

I am not sure if I need the domain.

I have no domain installed and tried some different things.

```
            SMBClient client = new SMBClient();

            try {
                Connection connection = client.connect("192.168.1.75");
                AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("admin", "password123".toCharArray(),null);
                Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);
                //DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare("Intel");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                txt.setText(e.toString());
            }
```

The following is from the SMBJ Website on GIT:
https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj

```
SMBClient client = new SMBClient();

try (Connection connection = client.connect("SERVERNAME")) {
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("USERNAME", "PASSWORD".toCharArray(), "DOMAIN");
    Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);

    // Connect to Share
    try (DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare("SHARENAME")) {
        for (FileIdBothDirectoryInformation f : share.list("FOLDER", "*.TXT")) {
            System.out.println("File : " + f.getFileName());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error log I get:

```
2022-04-25 11:45:27.475 22865-22865/com.example.filme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.filme, PID: 22865
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory;
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.SMBClient.<clinit>(SMBClient.java:119)
        at com.example.filme.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30213)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.filme/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.filme/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~SMMMBpkYv1Fu0fT2H1M_sA==/com.example.filme-ovE-fLeCY69AhQvQzyn1cA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~SMMMBpkYv1Fu0fT2H1M_sA==/com.example.filme-ovE-fLeCY69AhQvQzyn1cA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.hierynomus.smbj.SMBClient.<clinit>(SMBClient.java:119) 
        at com.example.filme.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769) 
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30213) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
2022-04-25 11:45:27.518 22865-22865/com.example.filme I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22865 SIG: 9
```

tried to install library slf4j-android-1.7.9.jar
but dont works for now.

Edit 12:46 o clock:

I added now many libraries and now its going close to work but not fully.

No library is missing but the following error occurs:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error

I read that I must do asynchronous processing.

But I'm too stupid to write this asynchronous code.. can anyone help?

Comment: `txt.setText(e.toString())` Wel.. shouldnt you tell us?

Comment: I tried out to give the error Message to my TextView
Did not work.
But even without that line it is crashing anyway

Comment: Then first Log.e() the exception message. And post the stacktrace from the logcat and other relevant lines. Tell which exception -that you do not catch- lets your app crash. Are you using threads or such? Add prStackTrace() to all catch blocks.

Comment: Where can i find the log message when i run it from my Samsung Phone?
When i run it from Virtual Device there is no Network.
Iam making APK Files and run it direct on my device.
I dont know how to debug there or where the log file is.

Comment: Use the LogCat window of Android Studio.

Comment: I am not connected with the PC.
I just copy the apk. Install it and then run it.
I dont know how to run the App with Android Studio and USB ADB Debugging.
I activated ADB Debugging in my Phone but when i connect my Phone the phone is not there in the Device Manager.

Comment: I try it on another PC to connect my phone and run Debugging.
I tell you later. Thanks for now. :-)

Comment: Following Error i get in logcat:

     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.filme/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~SMMMBpkYv1Fu0fT2H1M_sA==/com.example.filme-ovE-fLeCY69AhQvQzyn1cA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~SMMMBpkYv1Fu0fT2H1M_sA==/com.example.filme-ovE-fLeCY69AhQvQzyn1cA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]

Comment: Next time please post lines from logcat in your post to keep them readable. And.. do not just post errors but comment on them too.

Comment: `Caused by:` You omitted lines. Which error/exception was caused?

Comment: I added/edited the error log.
Hopefully someone could help...

Answer (score 0):

Now its working.

I needed following LIBRARIES:

asn-one-0.6.0.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.70.jar
mbassador-1.3.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar
slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar
smbj-0.11.5.jar